# Does this patent cover anything that can be construed as "Router Milling Technology?"

Tags: us9009986

Just wondering if there's anything in this patent that covers a technology.
[Video for Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igJsMdfm3G8&index=2&list=PLtGkwA1Fvkj817muQMVJq8IJaAMtYtBop&t=10s)

Comment: A patent covers what its claims state. No more and no less. Read the patent for yourself to answer your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question?

Comment: George, Eric, thank you for your responses.  The company holding this patent has publicly claimed that they hold a patent on "Router Milling Technology," and has threatened to sue other manufacturers whose products also employ a handheld router in the performance of the intended work.     And while they have made numerous Independent and Dependent claims in their patent, as long as a competing product does not infringe upon of all the elements of any one of their Claims, notwithstanding the Doctrine of Equivalents, nothing should bar the employment of a router to perform the work, correct?

Comment: @KialDowns correct. But interpreting claims is tricky. Still, I don't even know what milling means, maybe you could edit the question and make it clearer what you want to know and what your thoughts on it are.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite , I hope that is a little more clear.  Interested to hear what you think.

Comment: The author of the reference video has a profound lack of understanding of patent law. I'd recommend that you read the patent for yourself and consult with competent patent law counsel as to the scope and nature of the patent. As with most things in life, you get what you pay for. Asking strangers for free legal advice on the Internet is not an intelligent thing to do if the answer you are looking for is of any value to you.  A.R.